# Why does bash thinks that 010 is 8?

Tags: bash

Why does bash think the number 010 = 8?

```
x=010
echo $x
  010
echo $(( x+0 ))
  8
echo $(( x-2 ))
  6
```

I thought it might be binary, but 010 = 10 = 2. So why does it get 8, and how can I make it think 010 = 10 (and 010 - 2 = 8)?

Comment: The leading `0` tells it to be octal.  If you just do `x=10` then `echo $((x+0))` then shows `10`.  Also, there is no need for the extra `$` with in the `()`.

Comment: In many number parsers, `010` means 8 because by putting a `0` in front means octal, similar to how putting `0x` in some languages means hex.

Comment: This is actually an important thing to know when programming. In most languages `0` triggers octal, `0x` hex and `0b` binary.

Comment: @tim why would it -not- be 8? ;-) Oh not my downvote though but probably because it is too basic. It is pretty normal behaviour.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Number sequences starting with a `0` are interpreted as octal numbers.
Octal `10` = decimal `8`.

To get bash to treat it as a decimal number, remove the leading zero or force decimal with:

```
N=010
N=$((10#$N))
```

Generally that works for all bases, just replace the `10` with the base that you want:

```
N=[base#]n
```

Comment: Edited the question with two ways to solve it.

Comment: @Tim to do that you can use ${N%?} to chop the last digit and then ${N:-} to replace blank with 0.

Comment: @Tim if so I couldn't figure out how. ${${N%?}:-0} works in zsh but not in bash or ksh. (Also, `:-` in my comment above should have been `:-0`}

Comment: You should include in your answer that you can force any base with the  "*form [base#]n, where base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base*" [source: bash ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic)