# Bash 12 - 08 Value too great for base (error token "08")

Tags: bash, scripts

So, I'm trying to calculate `12-08` (not `12-8`) and get the following error:

```
let: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Here's the sample code:

```
first=12
second=08
if [[ ($first > $second) ]]; then
    let fin=first-second
else
    let fin=second-first
fi
```

P.S Sorry about the spacings

Comment: See [Why does bash thinks that 010 is 8?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621500/why-does-bash-thinks-that-010-is-8/621501#621501)

Answer (score 16):

If you precede a number by `0`, `bash` treats the number as octal. As octal is base 8 with digits ranging from 0 to 7, `08` is out of range for octal.

Now you have two options to do decimal calculation:

- Omit preceding 0:

  ```
  $ echo $(( 12 - 8 )) 
  4
  ```
- Explicitly mention base as decimal by `10#`:

  ```
  $ echo $(( 12 - 10#08 )) 
  4
  ```

Comment: @cat it's also used in i) the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`); ii) [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) (`var="foo"; echo ${var#f}`); iii) the `$#` variable; iv) the `!#` variable and a few other fringe cases here and there :) Have a look at `man bash | grep '#'`.

Comment: @cat: `#` only starts a comment when used at the beginning of a word.

Comment: At the beginning of a _word;_ e.g. `echo foo#bar #baz` will output `foo#bar` but not `#baz`, because the latter starts a comment.